How can I manipulate the syntax of an AT command and assign a method value in Python?
print(bytes(npArray))
print(bytes(npArray).hex())
ser.write(b'AT+DTRX=0,2,16,00003f0101007a00\r')
response = ser.read(100)
print(response.decode())

I have the above snippet in Python, which delivers this to me:
b'\x00\x00?\x01\x01\x00z\x00'

00003f0101007a00

Now my question is, how can the byte array or the hex string (they are the same value) be linked after the 3rd comma space in my AT (DTRX) command?
Bear in mind this is an "AT" LoRaWAN implementation so i assume the rules will be generic.
In my application on the other end I can receive if I simply paste the above value but it isn't working when I paste the method itself.

Well I've found a way, I simply added the above method inside brackets and after 3rd comma.
ser.write(f'AT+DTRX="0,2,16,{(bytes(npArray).hex())}"\r'.encode())
response = ser.read(100)
print(response.decode())

Being able now to send my hex string on the other end.
